# How to stop flex item going out of container

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, styles

Here below I have a link to my codepen which shows you the format for my header on my website. I'm struggling to understand why when the browser width is shortened that the nav goes off the line. What I'm trying to aim for is the nav to shrink with the header when the width is shortened. Any help would be thankful.

https://codepen.io/bulletman123/pen/QmBKdN

```
<body>
    <div class="headerBar">
        <h2>Tottenham Hotspur</h2>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Tickets</a></li>
                <li style="margin-right: 30px"><a href="learnHTML.html">Fixtures & Results</a></li>
                <li><a href="learnCSS.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="learnJS.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li style="width: 55px; margin-left: 85px; "><a href="learnJS.html" style="border-left: 0px;">Login</a></li>
                <li style="width: 70px; "><a href="learnJS.html" style="border-left: 2px solid rgb(155, 163, 168);">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </body>

nav{
    display: inline-block;
}

    nav ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    nav ul li{
        border: none;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 160px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(155, 163, 168);
    color: #102964;;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    }
    .headerBar{
        height: 80px;
        background-color:#d1d1d1;
        border-radius: 12px;
        box-shadow: 7px 6px 50px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
    .headerBar h2{
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #102964;
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

Comment: You have fixed widths on the `li`...try removing that.

Comment: Also you seem to be mixing `inline-block` with` inline-flex`...I'd stick with one layout method at a time.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use a width of auto?

Comment: Did you forget `flex-flow: row wrap`, by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In flex pages its better use % in places you using px, the px will make itens going out of container.

Comment: Thank you for the help I'm not sure why I didn't think that this was the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use .headerbar class as `display: flex` and remove the width from the li's.
then you've to tweak the width and padding a bit.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

go through the article once then come back to your problem you'll figure everything out.